# Mongo Date Query issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to retrieve some data from a collection on Mongo database for the past month and it is supposed to be run every month so I want to have a query that can run first day of the month to generate a report based on the query. So I was trying to use $lt and $gte to limit the date range. The date need to be filtered is one value inside an array.
For example:
Here is the collection data with the collection name Test:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1234528f4a224cdb39aaa"),
    "Project" : "12345",
    "Department" : "Sales",
    "Summary" : "TEST",
    "FirstName" : "Mary",
    "LastName" : "White",
    "activities" : [ 
        {
            "Type" : "Trip",
            "dateOfActivity" : ISODate("2020-12-20T06:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : "Conference",
            "dateOfActivity" : ISODate("2021-01-05T06:00:00.000Z"),
            "Note" : "test"
        }
    ]
```

So I would like to run a query to retrieve all the information with the dateofActivity for last 15 days. So I was using the following query:

```
db.Test.find( { 'activities.dateOfActivity': { $lt: new Date(), $gte :new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-15)) }})
```

I then noticed the returning records doesn't limit to all the activities in the past 15 days. I then tried to run the query :

```
db.Test.find( { 'activities.dateOfActivity': { $gte : ISODate("2021-02-04T06:00:00.000Z")}})
```

which doesn't limit the query records as well. The returning records contains some data from 12/27/2020. Where did I do wrong on the query?

Also what is the best way to just retrieve the result for the past month based on this dateofActivity field? For example, if I want to run this report first day of every month to retrieve the records for the last month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options for filtering the array in the response.

If you want only the first element that matches (which would work for that example document), use `$elemMatch` in a projection:

```
db.Test.find( {'activities.dateOfActivity': { $gte: date2, $lte: date1 }}, {activities: {$elemMatch:{dateOfActivity:{$gte: date2, $lte: date1})
```

If you need to get every matching elements, you would need to use aggregation.

Using unwind:

- Match to limit the rest of the pipeline to documents with at least one matching date
- Unwind the activities array
- Match only those activities in the date range

```
db.Test.aggregate([
   {$match: { 'activities.dateOfActivity':  { $gte: date2, $lte: date1 }}},
   {$unwind: "$activities"},
   {$match: { 'activities.dateOfActivity':  { $gte: date2, $lte: date1 }}}
])
```

Using filter:

- Match to select documents with a matching date
- Iterate each activities array with filter to eliminate non-matching elements

```
db.Test.aggregate([
   {$match: { "activities.dateOfActivity":  { $gte: date2, $lte: date1 }}},
   {$addFields: { 
         activities: {$filter: {
              input: "$activities",
              cond: {$and: [
                       {$gte: [ "$$this.dateOfActivity", date2]},
                       {$lte: [ "$$this.dateOfActivity", date1]}
              ]}
         }}
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input. I tried both options as you listed above. The first query works beautifully.  Yet the second one returns some syntax error : Error: Line 5: Unexpected token : It seems to me some brackets might be missing so I tried to add the closing brackets but still giving me the error. From the message, looks like it is complaining about line 5, input: "$activities" ?

Comment: Yeah, I typo'd that one pretty bad.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Joe. The modified query returns no errors this time but the result set doesn't seem to be correct. It returns the records with no dateofActivity value. Anything wrong ?

Comment: It seems to work on the sample data: https://mongoplayground.net/p/uXq8EDyyTYG Can you provide and example of it not working?

Comment: What is weird is that from the original collection, when I was using the second option, I got some data back with   "activities" : [] values. But when I create another collection and insert all the records with   "activities" : [] values, the query doesn't return those documents with   "activities" : []. I can not figure out why. So it might not be the data issue as using the same data set with the same query, I got wrong data for one time with the existing collection but got right data when I created new collections with inserting the same data. I tested multiple times. Very weird.